# 'What N is' or 'what is N' (affirmative statement)

Tags: conjunctions, subject-verb-agreement, inversion

In one online course, I saw the following phrase:

> In this video, you learned what is data and you also saw how not to
> misuse data.

My question is: shouldn't it be *'you learned what **data is**,'* since it is a simple affirmative statement which does not require any inversion?

Comment: You're quite right that *most* native speakers would express the "subject" (what you learned) in the "noun phrase" format **wh-word + subject + verb** rather than the "question inversion" format **wh-word + verb + subject** . Non-native speakers are much more likely to use the latter format. But that doesn't mean the less common format is "invalid". It's just less common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally one would say "*what data is*", and not the other way around. However, it may be that the title of a previous section in the training was posed as a question, ie '*what is data?*' and the speaker was referring back to this.